# Inline block ul with opacity causes end to cut off

Tags: css, google-chrome

https://jsfiddle.net/23ng6rqg/2/

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul > li {
  opacity: .5;
}
ul > li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>stuff</li>
  <li>stuff</li>
  <li>stuff</li>
  <li>stuff</li>
  <li>stuff</li>
  <li>stuff</li>
  <li>stuff</li>
  <li>stuff</li>
</ul>
```

In Chrome 43.0.2357.124 this CSS causes the tail in the last f of "stuff" to cut off. I can see that it has something to do with the width of the `ul`, as removing the `inline-block` (causing it to become full width) makes the behavior disappear.

I've tested this in IE and Firefox; this behavior does not occur in them.

Two questions with this:

1. Why does setting `ul` to `inline-block` cause the width to be too short for the tail of "f"?
2. Why does `opacity` cause items overflowing their parent to cut off?

Comment: I think no  browser can define an exact rule for fitting text in HTML elements. It is not caused by opacity, opacity just a case where this misbehaviour appeared clearly. By inspecting element and zooming, you can still see the problem of the tail of f without opacity. What I do regarding text placement is add some padding and use overflow (In other words, text is some non-regular component to put in regular HTML components)

Comment: If it's not opacity, why does the hover show the tail (setting opacity back to 1)?

Comment: That's what I said, it is not because of opacity, applying opacity just made the main problem more visible and more remarked. If you inspect element without opacity you will still see that the tail doesn't belong to current width of the `<li>`

Comment: It looks like something related to font rendering in chrome. When I set letter-spacing, this effect disappeared, the same when I changed font-family to Ubuntu-mono.

Comment: Which is why my question is a two parter. The second question is explicitly asking *why* opacity makes this problem more visible.

Comment: @dajnz,I agree with you. It is probably caused by the way chrome apply the font

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is actually occurring when opacity is applied to the `li` set the opacity to 1 as follows :

```
ul > li {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

the ' f ' won't be cut.

After some investigation, it seems using opacity with `inline-block` display has some effect on the text in webkit browsers where it would weaken the stroke, thus affecting the default width of the text where it is being getting overflown.

I managed to resolve this by adding `-webkit-text-stroke`. I guess this allows the browser to re-interpret the real stroke size relative to the pixel number set for the text-stroke property:

```
ul > li {
    opacity: .5;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.1px
}
```